# How will I access the components in the script inside a template?

Tags: javascript, html, web-component, shadow-dom

I would like reuse my html components that contains some javascript code, so for simplify I bring one simple example:

**index.html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <my-component></my-component>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**my-component.html**:

```
<template>
  <div id="something"></div>
  <script>
    // It doesn't work, this here is "window"
    document.getElementById("something").innerHTML = "Something"
  </script>
</template>
```

**index.js**:

```
window.makeComponent = (function () {
    function fetchAndParse(url) {
    return fetch(url, {mode: "no-cors"})
        .then(res => res.text())
        .then(html => {
        const parser = new DOMParser()
        const document = parser.parseFromString(html, 'text/html')
        const head = document.head
        const template = head.querySelector('template')
        return template
        })
    }
    function defineComponent(name, template) {
    class UnityComponent extends HTMLElement {
        connectedCallback() {
        const shadow = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'})
        shadow.appendChild(document.importNode(template.content, true))
        }
    }
    return customElements.define(name, UnityComponent)
    }
    function loadComponent (name, url) {
    fetchAndParse(url).then((template) => defineComponent(name, template))
    }

    return {loadComponent}
}())
makeComponent.loadComponent("my-component", "my-component.html")
```

I can with this code, but it copy all variables of the script to window:

```
<template>
  <div id="something"></div>
  <style onload="templFunc.apply(this.getRootNode())"></style>
  <script>
    function templFunc() {
    // It works
    let text = "Something"
    this.querySelector('#something').innerHTML = text
    // but...
    console.log(window.text) // => "Something"
    }
  </script>
</template>
```

It doesn't make a sense, if the script is inside the template at least should can access the elements inside the template, else the template is almost not util for the javascript, so, I can't understand the intention of use script inside the template or how to reuse the web components that use javascript, Is it wrong do this?

So, How to I access the components in the script inside a template without copy all script variables to window?

Comment: You could make your index file php and include or require the components from there.

Comment: I'm not using php.

Answer (score 1):

As you found out `<script>` inside a `<template>` runs in **Global scope**

If you use Angular, note Angular bluntly **removes** all `<script>` content from Templates.

One workaround is to add an HTML element that triggers code **within** Element scope.

`<img src onerror="[CODE]">` is the most likely candidate:

This then can call a Global function, or run `this.getRootNode().host` immediatly.

```html
<template id=scriptContainer>
  <script>
    console.log("script runs in Global scope!!");

    function GlobalFunction(scope, marker) {
      scope = scope.getRootNode().host || scope;
      console.log('run', marker, 'scope:', scope);
      scope.elementMethod && scope.elementMethod();
    }
  </script>

  <img src onerror="(()=>{
    this.onerror = null;// prevent endless loop if function generates an error
    GlobalFunction(this,'fromIMGonerror');
  })()">

</template>

<my-element id=ONE></my-element>
<my-element id=TWO></my-element>

<script>
  console.log('START SCRIPT');
  customElements.define('my-element',
    class extends HTMLElement {
      connectedCallback() {
        console.log('connectedCallback', this.id);
        this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' })
            .append(scriptContainer.content.cloneNode(true));
      }
    });

</script>
```

More detailed playground, including injecting SCRIPTs, at: https://jsfiddle.net/WebComponents/q0k8ts6b/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution,

**my-component**:

```
<template>
  <div id="something"></div>
  <script>
    makeComponent.getComponent("my-component", "something").innerHTML = "Something"
  </script>
</template>
```

**index.js**:

```js
window.makeComponent = (function () {
  function fetchAndParse(url) {
    return fetch(url, { mode: "no-cors" })
      .then((res) => res.text())
      .then((html) => {
        const parser = new DOMParser();
        const document = parser.parseFromString(html, "text/html");
        const head = document.head;
        const template = head.querySelector("template");
        return template;
      });
  }
  function defineComponent(name, template) {
    class UnityComponent extends HTMLElement {
      connectedCallback() {
        const shadow = this.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });
        this.setAttribute("id", name);
        shadow.appendChild(document.importNode(template.content, true));
      }
    }
    return customElements.define(name, UnityComponent);
  }
  function getComponent(host, query) {
    return document.getElementById(host).shadowRoot.querySelector(query);
  }
  function loadComponent(name, url) {
    fetchAndParse(url).then((template) => defineComponent(name, template));
  }

  return { getComponent, loadComponent };
})();
makeComponent.loadComponent("my-component", "my-component.html");
```

However I think that this is not the better way, maybe I need use the events here, and pass the shadow scope to a listener that is called in the script tag in the template, but I don't know how to pass the scope to the event yet.

> Up:

With events:

**my-component**:

```
<template>
  <div id="something"></div>
  <script>
     document.addEventListener("custom-event", (e) => {
         console.log(e.detail.target.shadowRoot.getElementById("date-year"));
     })
  </script>
</template>
```

**index.js**:

```js
window.makeComponent = (function () {
  function fetchAndParse(url) {
    return fetch(url, { mode: "no-cors" })
      .then((res) => res.text())
      .then((html) => {
        const parser = new DOMParser();
        const document = parser.parseFromString(html, "text/html");
        const head = document.head;
        const template = head.querySelector("template");
        return template;
      });
  }
  function defineComponent(name, template) {
    class UnityComponent extends HTMLElement {
      connectedCallback() {
        const shadow = this.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });
        shadow.appendChild(document.importNode(template.content, true));
        const event = new CustomEvent("custom-event", {'detail': {
            target: this
        }});
        document.dispatchEvent(event);
      }
    }
    return customElements.define(name, UnityComponent);
  }
  function loadComponent(name, url) {
    fetchAndParse(url).then((template) => defineComponent(name, template));
  }

  return { loadComponent };
})();
makeComponent.loadComponent("my-component", "my-component.html");
```

However, I prefer the first solution even. But if you need of nested components the first doesn't work, you need of the second.